# What is absolutly wrong in my js javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I cant understand why my browser say, unexpected token...

```
function decode(a) {
    a = a.replace("14","a");
    return a:
}

decode("14lpine");
```

What do you think is wrong in my code, im already try a big number of times, and not works.

Comment: Typo: `:` should be `;`

Comment: thanks so much @Barmat

Comment: i will try, but im noob in javascript

Comment: @Barmar thanks so much youre right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two points after (return a:), you have to change to this:

```
function decode(a) {
    a = a.replace("14","a");
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I will try, let me check...

Comment: what is the difference with comma or two points?

Comment: @pimuvexupu `;` is the statement terminator, `:` is used to mark statement labels and keys in object literals.

Comment: The comma in javascript is used for a json files, and the two points is not usual in javascript, in javascript is the simbol point and comma ; ?

Comment: @pimuvexupu Don't waste time posting an answer to trivial typo questions.

Comment: @wulabohafu, the colon `:` is a separator between keys and values in objects.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!

Comment: oh, now i understand...

Comment: @wulabohafu, that is the exactly point of all right!

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Exactly, the two points is used in Objects;

Comment: @Barmar You are right too...

Comment: Thanks so much to all, thats right, my mistake was the two points lol